# The scene isn't rendered (three.js)

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I've created a simple scene in three.js, but it doesn't works with canvas renderer (but it should work...)

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/PRkcJ/

It only works, if I use webGLrenderer. But why?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm stabbing in the dark here but I feel like Canvas is only for 2D rendering and you are trying to render a 3D mesh with lighting and a perspective camera. Surely this isn't applicable to 2D?

Comment: Fair enough. An upvote for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are getting is a white plane on a white background.

The light position for directional lights is treated as a direction vector and it must be of unit length.

Your code works if you do something like this:

```
light.position.set(-100, 150, 0).normalize();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PRkcJ/1/